# xamarin properties IOS IPA Options configuration 'ad-hoc' and 'App Store' disappeared

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, ipa

Xamarin properties IOS IPA Options configuration 'ad-hoc' and 'App Store' disappeared.

[image]

How to Distribution (ad-hoc and App store) build?

Comment: Have you checked that your Distribution Profile is set up correctly? https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/app_distribution/app-store-distribution/publishing_to_the_app_store/#Creating_and_Installing_a_Distribution_Profile

Comment: updated image link

Comment: set up Distribution Profile. 
find solution .ipa file create
1 properties -> iOS IPA Option -> 'Build ad-hoc/enterprise package(IPA)'
2. check. iphone connect.
3. release bliud
4. project folder open
5.use .ipa file /bin/iphone/release/projectname buliddate in folder

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and I fixed by adding the following node into the .csproj file of your ios project.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Ad-Hoc|iPhone' ">
    <DebugType>none</DebugType>
    <Optimize>True</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\iPhone\Ad-Hoc</OutputPath>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <ConsolePause>False</ConsolePause>
    <MtouchArch>ARMv7, ARM64</MtouchArch>
    <BuildIpa>True</BuildIpa>
    <CodesignProvision>Automatic:AdHoc</CodesignProvision>
    <CodesignKey>iPhone Distribution</CodesignKey>
    <CodesignEntitlements>Entitlements.plist</CodesignEntitlements>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'AppStore|iPhone' ">
    <DebugType>none</DebugType>
    <Optimize>True</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\iPhone\AppStore</OutputPath>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <ConsolePause>False</ConsolePause>
    <MtouchArch>ARMv7, ARM64</MtouchArch>
    <CodesignProvision>Automatic:AppStore</CodesignProvision>
    <CodesignKey>iPhone Distribution</CodesignKey>
    <CodesignEntitlements>Entitlements.plist</CodesignEntitlements>
</PropertyGroup>
```